# Pandas transform quarterly date-indexed dataframe into daily-indexed dataframe of recent sums

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a question related to pandas.
I have a date-indexed dataframe of the company's quarterly free cash flow values in the following form:

```
2015-03-31: -105703000.0 
2015-06-30: 131364000.0
2015-09-30: 68858000.0
2015-12-31: -25890000.0
2016-03-31: -98518000.0
```

I need to obtain the date-indexed dataframe of company's free cash flow for ttm i.e. it should contain a sum of the previous four quarterly free cash flow values for each day starting from the date of the 4-th report until today.

e.g. for each day since `2016-01-01`until `2016-03-30` value should be `-105703000.0 + 131364000.0 + 68858000.0 -25890000.0 = 68629000.0`

Is there a way to transform data to a required form using pandas tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution in a [manual](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.12.0/missing_data.html#cleaning-filling-missing-data).

```py
target_series = (
        source_series
        .rolling(min_periods=4, window=4)
        .sum()
        .dropna()
    )
```

Parameter `window` here states that rolling will sum 4 previous values.

Parameter `min_period` states that the first 3 rows will have a value of NaN as they don't have at least 4 previous rows